# Ask for a year, until it's between 2012 and 2016

Tags: c#

It works if I give a number between 2012 and 2016 but if not it should be asking until it becomes true.

```
        Console.Write("Year: ");
        int input =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (input >= 2012)
        {
            if (input <= 2016)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Year: ");
            Console.ReadLine(); //ask again until becomes true
        }
```

Comment: Need to learn something about basic looping tecnique. And what if you type instead of a number a string like "Hello"?

Comment: Note that the `else` only applies to the first `if`.  So you'd need to combine them.  Second you really want a loop of some type instead if you want them to keep entering values until they give one in the desired range.

Comment: Encompass the whole thing in a while loop and break only if values are within the constraint

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must write it in a while or for loop so it continuos until its correct

```
    Console.Write("Year: ");
    int input =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while(input<2012 || input>2016)
    {
        Console.Write("Year: ");
        input= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
        Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Comment: @Klaus Gütter can you explain to the author as to why *it won't work*, it would be helpful.

Comment: This won't work: if the input value is outside the allowed range, the while loop will not be entered. You probably forgot to negate the condition. But even when this is corrected: look what happens if the entered value is higher than 2016.

Comment: No; no input whatever will pass the condition `input<2012 && input>2016`.

Comment: I ts correct now I ran it on vs 2019 and it worked but if you enter "2016" or "2012" it will also work

Comment: Try doing it without having to call `input = Convert...` twice.